# uniformly distributed random number generation

Tags: c++, math

Why does this code generates uniformly distributed numbers? I have some difficulties in understanding it. Could someone explain? Thanks.

```
int RandomUniform(int n) {  
  int top = ((((RAND_MAX - n) + 1) / n) * n - 1) + n;  
  int r;  
  do {  
    r = rand();  
  } while (r > top);  
  return (r % n);  
}
```

update: I do understand why rand()%n doesn't give you a uniformly distributed sequence. My question is why the

```
top = ((((RAND_MAX - n) + 1) / n) * n - 1) + n;
```

What's the concern here? I think a simple top = RAND_MAX / n * n would do.

Comment: why do you think it does generate a uniform distribution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function assumes that `rand()` is uniformly distributed; whether or not that is a valid assumption depends on the implementation of `rand()`.

Given a uniform `rand()`, we can get a random number in the range `[0,n)` by calculating `rand()%n`. However, in general, this won't be quite uniform. For example, suppose `n` is 3 and `RAND_MAX` is 7:

```
rand()      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
rand() % n  0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1
```

We can see that 0 and 1 come up with a probability of 3/8, while 2 only comes up with a probability of 2/8: the distribution is not uniform.

Your code discards any value of `rand()` greater or equal to the largest multiple of `n` that it can generate. Now each value has an equal probability:

```
rand()      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
rand() % n  0 1 2 0 1 2 X X
```

So 0,1 and 2 all come up with a probability of 1/3, as long as we are not so unlucky that the loop never terminates.

Regarding your update:

> I think a simple top = RAND_MAX / n * n would do.

If `RAND_MAX` were an exclusive bound (one more than the actual maximum), then that would be correct. Since it's an inclusive bound, we need to add one to get the exclusive bound; and since the following logic compares with `>` against an inclusive bound, then subtract one again after the calculation:

```
int top = ((RAND_MAX + 1) / n) * n - 1;
```

However, if `RAND_MAX` were equal to `INT_MAX`, then the calculation would overflow; to avoid that, subtract `n` at the beginning of the calculation, and add it again at the end:

```
int top = (((RAND_MAX - n) + 1) / n) * n - 1 + n;
```

Answer (score 7):

The underlying problem is this: suppose you have a random number generator `my_rand()` that produces value from 0 to 6, inclusive, and you want to generate values from 0 to 5, inclusive; if you run your generator and return `my_rand() % 6`, you won't get a uniform distribution. When `my_rand()` returns 0, you get 0; when it returns 1, you get 1, etc. until `my_rand()` returns 6; in that case `my_rand() % 6` is 0. So overall, `my_rand() % 6` will return 0 twice as often as any other value. The way to fix this is to not use values greater than 5, that is, instead of `my_rand() % 5` you write a loop and discard values from `my_rand()` that are too large. That's essentially what the code in the question is doing. I haven't traced it through, but the usual implementation is to compute the largest multiple of `n` that is less than or equal to `RAND_MAX`, and whenever `rand()` returns a value that's greater than that multiple, go back and get a new value.

Comment: good explanation, but does still require that the input RNG does actually have a uniform distribution.

Comment: also, if `RAND_MAX` is big enough (which it usually is) and `n` is small enough then the difference the code above makes is negligible.

Comment: @Alnitak - depends on how pure you want to be.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah. I knew the problem. I was wondering why the code doesn't just use top = RAND_MAX / n * n which computes a multiple of n very closet to RAND_MAX

Answer (score 2):

I didn't trace through the code that computes top, but `RAND_MAX` is the largest value that `rand()` can return; `(RAND_MAX + 1) / n * n` would be a better ceiling, but if `RAND_MAX` is, say, `INT_MAX`, the result would be unpredictable. So maybe all that code is trying to avoid overflow.

Comment: Thanks. I think I get it. That's right, n should divide RAND_MAX + 1. and the code do RAND_MAX + 1 - n then do / n * n, which avoids overflow. Thanks.

Comment: For some values of `n` it would produce a lower value, which would, in turn, waste more random numbers than necessary. For example, if `RAND_MAX` is odd (which it typically is), and `n` is `(RAND_MAX + 1)/2`, then on average the code would call `rand()` twice for every random number that it generated.

Comment: Consider what your option `(RAND_MAX/n)*n` would do for `n = RAND_MAX-1`.

Comment: @JackAidley Good Point. I haven't considered that.